# change the Label text when case happens

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to change the lblsource and lblmessage when case happens how do I do this?

```
 <div class="form-horizontal well container-cus">         
 <div class="row">             
 <div class="col-lg-12">                 
 <br />                 
 <br />                 
 <div style="width: 350px; box-shadow: 5px 0px 40px rgba(0,0,0, .2);" class="panel panel-warning center-block">                     
 <div class="panel-heading">
 </div>                     
 <div class="panel-body">                         
 <div class="form-group">                             
 <div class="row">                                 
 <div class="text-center">                                     
 <img class="profile-img" src="/Images/user_icon.png" />                                 
 </div>                            
 </div>                             
 <br />                             
 <div class="row">                                 
 <div class="col-lg-12">                                     
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Username" runat="server" required></asp:TextBox>                                 
 </div>                             
 </div>                         
 </div>                         
 <div class="form-group">                             
 <div class="row">                                 
 <div class="col-lg-12">                                     
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" required></asp:TextBox>                                 
 </div>                             
 </div>                         
 </div>                         
 <br />                         
 <br />                         
 <div class="panel-footer">                             
 <div class="row">                                 
 <div class="col-lg-12">                                     
 <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" Style="width: 290px;" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg pull-right" runat="server" Text="LOGIN" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" />                                 
 </div>                             
 </div>                         
 </div>                      
 </div>                     
 <asp:Label ID="lblsource" runat="server" CssClass="text-danger" Text=""></asp:Label>                     
 <br />                     
 <asp:Label ID="lblmessage" runat="server" CssClass="text-danger" Text=""></asp:Label>                     
 <br />                     
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="text-danger" Text="Invalid Username or Password" Visible="false"></asp:Label>                 
 </div>                              
 </div>         
 </div>     
 </div>
```

the above code is my .aspx when logging in the lblsource and lblmessage .text value must be change when it enters a certain case in the switch statement

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class Account_Suppliers_Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Helper.GetCon()))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT su.SupplierID, su.Status, ut.Username, ut.Password, ut.UserID FROM UserTable ut INNER JOIN Suppliers su ON su.UserID = ut.UserID Where ut.Username = '" + txtUsername.Text + "' AND ut.Password = '" + Helper.CreateSHAHash(txtPassword.Text) + "'", con);

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    Session["SupplierID"] = dr["SupplierID"].ToString();
                    Session["Status"] = dr["Status"].ToString();
                    Session["Username"] = dr["Username"].ToString();
                    Session["UserID"] = dr["UserID"].ToString();
                }

                string statuscode = Session["Status"].ToString();


                switch (statuscode)
                {
                    case "Active":
                        Session["Status"] = null;
                        Session.Remove("Status");
                        Response.Redirect("\\Account\\Suppliers\\Default.aspx");
                        break;

                    case "Inactive":

                        lblsource.Text = "Login Page: INACTIVE";
                        lblmessage.Text = "Welcome Back! Please let us know on how we can help you better.";
                        Response.Redirect("\\Account\\Suppliers\\Login.aspx");
                        break;

                    case "Pending":
                        lblsource.Text = "Login Page: PENDING";
                        lblmessage.Text = "Thank you for registering with us. We will process your request shortly.";
                        lblsource.Visible = true;
                        lblmessage.Visible = true;

                        Response.Redirect("\\Account\\Suppliers\\Login.aspx");
                        break;

                    case "Blocked":
                        lblsource.Text = "Login Page: BLOCKED";
                        lblmessage.Text = "We are so glad to hear from you. Please settle your account.";
                        lblsource.Visible = true;
                        lblmessage.Visible = true;
                        Response.Redirect("\\Account\\Suppliers\\Login.aspx");
                        break;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Visible = true;
            }




    }

    private DataSet GetRecordSuppplier(string TableName)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Helper.GetCon()))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " + TableName + " WHERE SupplierID = '" + Session["SupplierID"] + "'";
            SqlDataAdapter da;
            da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, TableName);

            return ds;
                }
}
```

the above code is my .aspx.cs 
I just want to change the value of lblsource and lblmessage when case happens

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do `Response.Redirect` is you are staying on the same page. So your redirect to Default makes sense, but redirects to Login page does not, as you are already on the Login page.

Just remove these redirects, and let the page finish the processing, and you'll see the updates to labels applied as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your button click code should like this:

```
 protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Helper.GetCon()))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT su.SupplierID, su.Status, ut.Username, ut.Password, ut.UserID FROM UserTable ut INNER JOIN Suppliers su ON su.UserID = ut.UserID Where ut.Username = '" + txtUsername.Text + "' AND ut.Password = '" + Helper.CreateSHAHash(txtPassword.Text) + "'", con);

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    Session["SupplierID"] = dr["SupplierID"].ToString();
                    Session["Status"] = dr["Status"].ToString();
                    Session["Username"] = dr["Username"].ToString();
                    Session["UserID"] = dr["UserID"].ToString();
                }

                string statuscode = Session["Status"].ToString();


                switch (statuscode)
                {
                    case "Active":
                        Session["Status"] = null;
                        Session.Remove("Status");
                        Response.Redirect("\\Account\\Suppliers\\Default.aspx");
                        break;

                    case "Inactive":

                        lblsource.Text = "Login Page: INACTIVE";
                        lblmessage.Text = "Welcome Back! Please let us know on how we can help you better.";

                        break;

                    case "Pending":
                        lblsource.Text = "Login Page: PENDING";
                        lblmessage.Text = "Thank you for registering with us. We will process your request shortly.";
                        lblsource.Visible = true;
                        lblmessage.Visible = true;


                        break;

                    case "Blocked":
                        lblsource.Text = "Login Page: BLOCKED";
                        lblmessage.Text = "We are so glad to hear from you. Please settle your account.";
                        lblsource.Visible = true;
                        lblmessage.Visible = true;

                        break;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Visible = true;
            }




    }
```